# This file does not belong to any project Code insight might not work properly when opening project in clion

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, clion

I am a total newbie in C programming and Clion interfaces, so **please share the screenshot** for me to understand it better. Recently I downloaded a training file .c when I open it in CLion, the compiler won't work. Instead, the compiler generated my other .c file. So far CLion works fine, but somehow CLion has the problem with this downloaded files. Although they work fine in CodeBlocks, How to fix this?

[Clion file does not belong_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc8c1.png)
Here is my training file [c-learn](https://dropmefiles.com/t654p)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and provide a [mcve]. Moreover, please avoid the use of screenshots and actually post your relevant errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new executable to new file.
You need to open CMakeLists.txt and add something like
`add_executable(foo 02-12_value2.c)`

Comment: thanks, Maxim! you just need to add foo your_c_file_name